# Can I use 'res.sendFile' and 'res.json' together?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Currently I'm using a controller within my Express app to handle routing. When a certain route is hit I call `pagesController.showPlayer` which serves my `index.html`. Here is the controller:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');

var player = function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../assets', 'index.html'));
};

module.exports = {
  player: player
};
```

I need to also send back a JSON object representing the user who is requesting this route.
However, when I add `res.json({user: req.user});` all I get back is this JSON object, `index.html` is no longer shown.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `res.json()` represents the HTTP response that an Express app sends when it gets an HTTP request. On the other hand, `res.sendFile()` transfers the file at the given path.

In both cases, the flow is essentially transferred to client who might have made the request.

So no, you cannot use `res.sendFile` and `res.json` together.

However, you do have few workarounds to achieve the desired goal:

res.sendFile have the following signature:

```
res.sendFile(path [, options] [, fn])
```

Where `path` must be an absolute path of the file(Unless the root option is set in the options object).

In `options`, you can specify the `object` containing HTTP headers to serve with the file.

example:

```
  var options = {
    headers: {
        'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
        'x-sent': true,
        'name': 'MattDionis',
        'origin':'stackoverflow' 
    }
  };

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../assets', 'index.html'), options);
```

Thats really the closest you can do to achieve the desired task. There are other options too..

- like setting content in a cookie(but that'll be a part of each subsequent req/res cycle), or
- sending just a json response (with `res.json`) and manage routing at client side(while nodejs will serve as an API end), or
- set [res.locals](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals) object that contain variables scoped to the request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during that request / response cycle (if any)

Hope it Helps!

Comment: I'm just using headers as you hints and it works just fine. Thanks for tip!

Comment: This solution may work, but i think it's bad because it can be an attack vector. Ill intended users may inject data that will end up used as headers.

Comment: How do I get access to the headers from the html file? Any idea?