# How to send parameters with res.sendFile() while serving static content and access them in UI controller?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

```
 var claims = [];
 app.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    claims = req.user['_json'];
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')));
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build/index.html'));
    });
```

Above route and middleware authenticates the user that is trying to log in to my application, I want the logged in user details to be sent to UI along with res.sendFile and access them in my angular2 .ts file. How can I do so?

claims has the logged in user details

Answer (score 0):

Using Express, you can't send a file and data at the same time. You will need to create two separate routes to get your user details and the webpage.

See this answer for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31461737/4719679