# How to append a JSON descriptor to res.sendFile() in Express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server

After `passport` authenticating success i want to pass the `req.user` data to the component

using `res.sendFile()`.

I found this answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461358/can-i-use-res-sendfile-and-res-json-together/31461737#31461737)

But i don't know how to read the `options` param on the component in `componentDidMount()`

Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way to send mixed JSON + file content by using just the `sendFile()` method. As a workaround, you can send your JSON data as a custom response header:

```
const options = {
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'User',
        'User': JSON.stringify(req.user),
    }
};

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../assets', 'index.html'), options);
```

Note that the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header is required, in order for your client to always be able to access the extra header.

Then, assuming you are using `axios` on the frontend:

```
axios.get(YOUR_URL, response => {
    const user = JSON.parse(response.headers['User']);

    console.log('User Object', user);
});
```

With `fetch`:

```
response.headers.get('User');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But i already can handle it using `axios` and this bothering me because it causes a little slow moving when open the page.

Is there any other way to handle it to avoid `axios ajax fetch` methods ?

Comment: The only way for browser-side JavaScript to process an endpoint response is to fetch data, regardless of the data (or file) format. The most basic alternative, if you want to avoid using libraries, is to use a standard XMLHttpRequest.